# MPMoviePlayerViewController with embedded video within UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to get an embedded video playback properly implemented within a tab-bar navigation. In my specific case, the video shall be displayed in a non-fullscreen manner on a UIView that is hosted by a UIViewController, managed by a UITabBarController.

For simplifying the example, lets say I have two tabs within my tabbar. First one shows some random stuff, second one shows the viewcontroller that hosts the embedded video.

Once the user selects the second tab, the video is loading and playing properly.

For initializing the player, I am using the following code from within my UIView derived class, triggered by the initializer (initWithFrame):

```
- (void)initPlayback
{
     self.movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
     movieViewController_.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
     movieViewController_.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
     [self addSubview:self.movieViewController.view];
}
```

For starting the playback, I am using the following code, triggered by the viewWillAppear method of my UIViewController derived class:

```
- (void)playVideo
{
     [movieViewController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:fileURL_];
}
```

If then, the user selects the first tab (while the video is still playing), I am making sure that the video is stopped as it would continue playing if that was not done:

```
- (void)stopVideo
{
     [movieViewController_.moviePlayer stop];
}
```

Once the user selects the second tab again, the view stays blank, nothing is loaded or played even though the playVideo-method is invoked.

What am I missing, why is the video playback failing when reselecting the second tab?

==========new attempt=============

This time I stopped relying on shouldAutoplay (as suggested) but that did not make a difference.

Adapted and added code for this;

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (movieViewController_.moviePlayer.loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable &&
        movieViewController_.moviePlayer.playbackState != MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        [movieViewController_.moviePlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)deregisterFromNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                  object:nil];

}


- (void)registerForNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)initPlayback
{
    NSLog(@"playback init...");
    self.movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
    movieViewController_.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    movieViewController_.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    movieViewController_.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    movieViewController_.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0.0f;
    [self addSubview:movieViewController_.view];
}

- (void)playVideo
{
    NSLog(@"playback starting...");
    [self registerForNotifications];
    [movieViewController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:fileURL_];
}

- (void)stopVideo
{
    NSLog(@"playback stopping...");
    [movieViewController_.moviePlayer stop];
    [self deregisterFromNotifications];
}
```

Comment: omg, the answer was so simple, I am hesitating to write it as an answer.... by adding [movieViewController_.moviePlayer prepareToPlay] to my playVideo method, things started to work just fine and as expected. Does not make sense to me but it works.

Comment: Congratulations! Yay! It was unclear to me that you were playing over the network. `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable` as a loadstate means that you have downloaded enough of the movie so that the phone is comfortable playing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [movieViewController_.moviePlayer prepareToPlay] to my playVideo method does the trick  (when working with remote streams).

Answer (score 0):

In `playVideo` I think it should be
`[movieViewController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:fileURL_];`
`[movieViewController_.moviePlayer play];`

I assume that it works the first time because autoplay defaults to `YES`

Comment: For validating what you suggest I have added an explicit shouldAutoplay=NO within the initializer and added a play (as suggested) to my playVideo method; the result is that the player wont even work properly on the first visit to that tab. I am assuming this is caused by the video stream not being playable right away - will now try to register a loadstate handler to see if that helps...

Comment: No, that does not make a difference. shouldAutoplay remains in the same state, hence there should not be a difference. Still I did adapt my code as drafted in my edited question, still no luck....

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. If the second tab is dedicated to displaying video why not just use an instance of it as the root view controller for the second tab?

Comment: The second tab is not dedicated to playing the video alone. The video is played in an embedded, non-fullscreen fashion on that second viewcontroller (as described in my original question).

Comment: Are you aware that MPMoviePlayerViewController is intended to be displayed modally and show only full screen video? Check the documentation. You should embed an MPMoviePlayerController into your view.

Comment: I was indeed not aware that using a MPMoviePlayerViewController limits me to fullscreen only. Now that you spell it out, it does make sense as one of the paradigms is: one ViewController only per screen. Will try it without the MPMoviePlayerViewController, only relaying on MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: After adapting my example to use the MPMoviePlayerController directly (as opposed to using the MPMoviePlayerViewController), no changes happened on the results: as soon as I am switching from the active movie towards another tab and back, the video does not play anymore - looks as if the MPMoviePlayerController's view has problems once it gets invisible due to switching the tabs.